# Problems about iAD -AutoLayOut & Error

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I'm trying to add iAd into my app, but I have some questions. Can someone help me?

1- When I run the app, I get an error like 
*"2016-04-04 00:57:42.763 APPDraft1 [266:17483] Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=3, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}
2016-04-04 00:59:49.270 APPDraft1 [266:17483] Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=3, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}
2016-04-04 01:01:17.354 LYS Sayaç[266:17483] Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=1 "Service session terminated." UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=1002,* NSLocalizedDescription=Service session terminated.}"

2- Secondly, I made the lay-out as you can see on the picture. But I got an 
issue about the size. Xcode warns me, and I couldn't change the size of the banner. Cause it changes automaticly. How can I fix this.

First picture:[xcodes warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htYsa.png)

Second picture: [adbanner view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfVIA.png)

Here is my code:

import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate{

```
@IBOutlet weak var iAd: ADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    iAd.hidden = true
    iAd.delegate = self
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {

}
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.iAd.hidden = false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: You're creating two `ADBannerView`'s. Once with `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` and once in Interface Builder. Remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. Also, the iAd network is going to be discontinued. I'd suggest using a different ad network.

Comment: @Daniel Storm what's your suggestion? By the way thanks for the reply

Comment: @BuckyAk don't even bother implementing iAd. The iAd network is shutting down in June and any new apps submitted with the framework will not display ads. Only ads that were submitted and approved before January 15, 2016 will continue to display ads until the network shutdown in June.

Comment: Which ad Network are you suggesting? And where can I find the codes to implement the ad server to my app? Some kind of a guide I mean. Thanks for your answers by the way.